# CSS and HTML Mozilla Error

Tags: html, css, compatibility, mozilla

I've been writing my first HTML CSS website and I'm confused by what is messing up my navbar on Firefox because for some reason it's showing up above the page window. Is there a -moz- prefix that I am missing?
Here's the website: http://fightthefamine.org/

Comment: Your HTML is messed up, you don't close elements like this `</div id="content"></div id="wrapper">`. You just need `</div>`

Comment: You also have a negative margin on `.homepage .navbar` which means you can't see it, as it forces it off screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace .homepage .navbar with the following in your CSS.

```
.homepage .navbar {
display: inline-table;
position: relative;
top: -30px;
}
```